# How hand 100k WebSocket sessions and support interaction between them

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I am writing a server that should handle 100k WebSocket sessions and support interaction between them, something like a real-time messenger.  But I don't understand how I should handle all active sessions on the server-side.

The main requirement is that I have to interact, for example, to be able to send messages from one user to another.

Comment: Why 100k, do you already have something that works for 10 sessions? If you don't, 100k sessions is out of your reach, like trying to do heart surgery without having studied anatomy

Comment: Yes, when a new user is connected, I add her session to Map, but I understand that it a bad idea for the handle  a lot of users

Comment: I want to understand what a correct way to handle a lot of sessions

Comment: Ok so what breaks when you add more and more users? Can you handle 300 users? 1000? 3000? 100k will likely requiere a complete rewrite and tuning OS parameters but you won't know what you need until you get at that point

Comment: Almost certainly you need a design where the sessions are handled by multiple servers.  (100k is greater than the 64k limit on local TCP port numbers.)

Comment: You need multiple IP address to overcome that limitation, not necessarily multiple servers

Comment: You can user JMS broker for scaling your server , it can be activeMQ or RabbitMQ etc.